# Session variables not setting correctly

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am trying to set a session variable from page to another. It was working on my localhost but then I uploaded it to my server and now it fails. I have done some basic bug tests, and it will print at specific points, I have labeled them in the code. Here is the code the code I am using

//PAGE 1

```
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){

    $_SESSION['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];
    //prints here just fine then fails after
    header('location: app.php');

}elseif($_POST){

    if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }

    $questions = array();

    for($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++){
        $questions['q'.$i] = $_POST['q'.$i];
    }

    $check = "";
    foreach($questions as $key => $val){
        $check .= $val;
    }
    $metreq = strcmp($check, "1111-1-1-1-11-1-1");

    if(!$metreq){
        $_SESSION['questionaire'] = $questions;
        header("location: app.php");
    }else{
        header('location: nq.php');
    }
}
```

///PAGE 2

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
require_once('inc/state_list_options.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['questionaire']) || isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $id = $first_name = $middle_name = $last_name = $suffix = $address = $city = $state = $zip = $phone_area = $phone_exch =
    $phone_num = $phone2_area = $phone2_exch = $phone2_num = $email_address = $birth_month = $birth_day = $birth_year =
    $job = $referred = "";
    $selected = "selected";
    $questions = array();
    //here we will generate a session id that is the code passed from the link clicked by the user
    $conn = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password');
    mysql_select_db('db', $conn);
    if($conn){
        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $q = "SELECT * FROM eagle.pre_application WHERE id = '$id'";    

            $r = mysql_query($q, $conn);
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);

            $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            $middle_name = $row['middle_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            $suffix = $row['suffix'];
            $address = $row['address'];
            $city = $row['city'];
            $state = $row['state'];
            $zip = $row['zip'];
            $phone_area = $row['phone_area'];
            $phone_exch = $row['phone_exch'];
            $phone_num = $row['phone_num'];
            $phone2_area = $row['phone2_area'];
            $phone2_exch = $row['phone2_exch'];
            $phone2_num = $row['phone2_num'];
            $email_address = $row['email_address'];
            $birth_month = $row['birth_month'];
            $birth_day = $row['birth_day'];
            $birth_year = $row['birth_year'];
            $questions['q1'] = $row['q1'];
            $questions['q2'] = $row['q2'];
            $questions['q3'] = $row['q3'];
            $questions['q4'] = $row['q4'];
            $questions['q5'] = $row['q5'];
            $questions['q6'] = $row['q6'];
            $questions['q7'] = $row['q7'];
            $questions['q8'] = $row['q8'];
            $questions['q9'] = $row['q9'];
            $questions['q10'] = $row['q10'];
            $questions['q11'] = $row['q11'];
            $_SESSION['questionaire'] = $questions;
        }
        $q2 = "SELECT job_posting.id, job_posting.title, location.city, location.state 
        FROM eagle.job_posting
        LEFT JOIN eagle.location
        ON job_posting.location__Id = location.id";
        $j = mysql_query($q2, $conn);
        ?>
           <!-- job application goes ehre -->
        <?  
    }else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Please fill out the questionaire before completing the applicationn.";
        header('location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}else{
    echo "There is an error";
}
?>
```

I'm not 100% sure where to go from this point forward. I was thinking that it was the headers causing and issue, but that has never appeared so at this poitn I am baffled. Please let me know what you think about this. If you need additional code or further examples please let me know and I can provide them for you. Thank you in advance to anyone who stops by to help!

EDITS/DEVELOPMENTS/UPDATES

9:07 AM: Using developer's tools on chrome it is now receiving a 500 server error when submitting to page 2

9:16 AM Removed errors found with the require_once(''); There was an error in the path. Now it just automatically goes to the redirect on page 2 even if a variable is manually passed in the header via the address bar. I'm stumped still. code updated to reflect changes

Comment: Sidenote: `header('location: xxx.php'); exit;` which you should do.

Comment: is this is a new standard practice I have never seen it before, and what are the benefits?

Comment: it prevents the rest of the script to execute. (exit) add it to all headers.

Comment: It's been standard practice since forever. It prevents unwanted information(if any) being sent further after sending a header.

Comment: many a time, it actually fixes code, I've seen it happen quite a few times

Comment: Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. That reveals errors if any are present.

Comment: *"Using developer's tools on chrome it is now receiving a 500 server error when submitting to page 2"* - check your logs.

Comment: there was an error with the path to the require_once('file.php'); but that wasn't the issue at hand. Even if I send a path ?id=4 through manually, for example, it just hits the redirect at the bottom regardless.

Comment: This `//do lots of stuff }*(missing else)*{ $_SESSION['error']` that is a factor, there's no `else` or `elseif` for those braces.

Comment: here let me add some content then, I just have to remove certain things because of secuirty

Comment: added more content for you @Fred -ii-

Comment: Your bracing is off for PAGE 2. There are missing `else` and/or `elseif` so you'll need to go over that and determine how each conditional ends as. especially for `//continue application and if info is pulled from database it will be displayed
    }
}{
        $_SESSION['error']`

Comment: There's also either a missing matching brace for the first `}` in => `}else{
    echo "There is an error";
}` or it needs to be removed.

Comment: after extracting the html and leaving the raw php, everything matches up correctly still no changes were made

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63039/discussion-between-mark-hill-and-fred-ii).

Comment: @MarkHill You can put in your own answer and mark it as solved (when Stack lets you) outlining what the actual problem was. I'm glad the problem was solved Mark, *cheers*